# manipulate each element differently returned by :gt() - possible?

Tags: jquery

I am returning first 3 `li` elements like so:

```
$('li:*gt(0):lt(3)').animate({
    'left' : 10
});
```

I would like to manipulate each one differently, right now I give each one a `left` with a value of `10`, but I would like the second and third `li` to have values of `100` and `200`, respectively.

Is this even possible?

Comment: Why dont you use `.each()` and then target the element accordingly.

Comment: because there might be 100 li elements, it is supposed to go 3 by 3.

Comment: But you can also target them that way inside. see the answer below.

Comment: it allows me to use the actual first element as well, otherwise 0 would be second element.

Comment: How is `:*gt(0):lt(3)` different from just `:lt(3)`?

Comment: the second li becomes the first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.each` and check the index:

```
var animateValues = [10, 100, 200],

$('li:*gt(0):lt(3)').each(function(i) {
    $(this).animate({
        'left' : animateValues[i % animateValues.length];
    });
});
```

Comment: but what if I have more li elements? Would it be possible to make it check the index dynamically?

Comment: Yes, that all depends on your rules.

Comment: so in your example how would i check for indexes of `0, 1 ,2` (since returned li elements are the first 3), without hardcoding the indexes?

Comment: are you going to have a different rule for each index? it's essentially going to center around multiplying the index by a set increment to set the animation appropriately

Comment: the first second and third would always have their own same rules, and so on  infinitely. so first would have a left of 10, second 100, third 200, fourth 10, fifth 100, sixth 200 etc.

Comment: Interesting - give me a minute

Comment: Use `animateValues[i % animateValues.length]`

Comment: @Barmar -- Yess! Couldn't think straight for some reason, edited :\